# Concerning AWK programming, what do the -f switch and ~ operator do?

Tags: awk, gawk, syntax

I can't seem to find anything on these switches. I know the "-F" option can be used to change the delimiter but that's the extent of what I've found other than it looks like maybe a compiling option; I may be way off.

I know that -f is a command line option, but I can't seem to find any other info on them. As for the ~ operator, I just don't know why you use it.

Comment: How else would you compare a string and a regex if not with `~`? And for `-f`, see, for example, [the GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Options).

Answer (score 3):

The [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Options) describes the option `-f` as:

`-f source-file` or `--file source-file`

> Read the awk program source from `source-file` instead of in the first nonoption argument. This option may be given multiple times; the awk program consists of the concatenation of the contents of each specified `source-file`.

As for the operators `~` and `!~`, they perform regular expression comparisons:

1. `exp  ~ /regexp/` -> is true, if the expression `exp` (taken as a string) matches the regular expression `regexp`
2. `exp !~ /regexp/` -> is true, if it doesn't match

**Random example**:

```sh
top -b -n 1|awk '$2 !~ /root/'|awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/'|head
```